# How to Access ninject .Net Container across Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject

I am trying to implement a simple application with the MVVM pattern using Dependency Injection With ninject.

The recommended way of using DI is to resolve all dependencies at just one point:

```
App()
{
   kernel = new StandardKernel();

   kernel.Bind<IService>().To<DefaultService>();   

   kernel.Bind<IMainWindow>().To<MainWindow>();
   // Register all other dependencies here

   // resolve all dependencies.      
   MainWindow mw = kernel.Get<IMainWindow>();

}
```

This is a very ideal scenario where all dependencies get resolved by just one call to the kernel and the kernel is not needed any more in the application.

However the problem is that there are "Views" in my application that need to be resolved e.g in the MainViewModel by just knowing the type of some specific UserControl that is only known at runtime.

The easiest way and at the same time worse (not recommended) is to pass the container as injected parameter in the constructor and then simply call:

```
void resolveByType(Type viewType)
{
    // Container was injected in this class (Dirty!!!).
    Container.Get(viewType)
}
```

This works fine but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same behaviour?

Comment: 1. ViewModels referencing or requiring Views tells you, you do it wrong. No-go in MVVM. 2. If your views require dependencies, why not resolve the View?

Comment: You are right with #1. I need to change that. However that still does not solve my problem of having to access the container in other classes. #2. that is what I am trying to do. var View = Container.Get(viewType) is resolving the view with its requiered dependencies.

Comment: Just not inside the ViewModel. Using the container or referencing views is fine, in Application Layer (where your Views and application related code is, so not the same assembly as your ViewModels). Take a look at the way Microsoft solved it with PRISM: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Mvvm/ViewModelLocator.cs. This allows the views to be resolved completely in and from XAML.